# Ruby array sort by multiple attributes

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

```
test = [["movie5name","2014"],["movie2name","2016"],["movie3name","2016"],["movie3name","2017"]]
testNew = test.sort_by{|n| [-n[1],n[0]]}
```

I was trying to sort above array by first sorting based on descending order of year then based on the acesding order of the movie name.
However, it shows undefined method error because the negative sign before n:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're trying to make a `string` negative, try following code:

```
testNew = test.sort_by{|n| [-n[1].to_i,n[0]]}
```

Assuming that `n[1]` is always convertible to a number.